# error while using enable-secure-admin

Tags: server, ssh, java, glassfish

I'm trying to install glassfish on a server (I also installed Java) but I got this error:

```
Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
No such local command: enable-secure-admin.  Unable to access the server to execute the command remotely.  Verify the server is available. 
Command enable-secure-admin failed.
```

I followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-glassfish-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-3

But when I try to use the `asadmin enable-secure-admin` command I got the error. Does someone knows why and what to do? :)